# Prove that the centralizer is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that the center of a group is a normal subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66052/prove-that-the-center-of-a-group-is-a-normal-subgroup)

Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that $C_{G}(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, where $C_{G}(H)$ is the centralizer of $H$ in $G$.

I have proved that $C_{G}(H)$ is a subgroup but how do I prove that it is normal - is this not obvious by the definition of a centralizer?

Comment: It is obvious by definition. Please have a try.

Comment: $C_{G}(H)$ := {$g \in G | ghg^{-1}=h,    \forall h \in H$} and we want to show that $C_{G}(H)$ is normal i.e. that $fC_{G}(H)f^{-1} \subseteq C_{G}(H)$ for all $f \in G$.

Can we just say that $fgf^{-1}=f(gf^{-1})=f(f^{-1}g)=(ff^{-1})g=g \subseteq G$ and this is true for all $f \in G$ hence $C_{G}(H)$ is normal in G.

Comment: Nooo.. $gf^{-1}\ne f^{-1}g$, unless we know sth like $g\in H$ and $f\in C_G(H)$, but this was not assumed here.

Comment: @draks: Not a duplicate. The question you refer to is focused on the subgroup property; this one is about normality.

Comment: Just another way of seeing normality: If $H$ is normal, then $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation with kernel $C_G(H)$, so as $C_G(H)$ is the kernel of the permutation representation in $S_H$ it is normal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $x\in C_G(H)$, and $g\in G$ arbitrary. Then, as $xh=hx$ for all $h\in H$, and $H$ is normal, thus $g^{-1}hg\in H$, we have
$$gxg^{-1}\cdot h=gx(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1} = g(g^{-1}hg)xg^{-1} = h\cdot gxg^{-1} .$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate your last statement?How you conclude that $C_G(H)$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: It's proven that for any $x\in C_G(H)$ and any $g\in G$, the conjugate $gxg^(-1}$ is exchangeable with any $h\in H$, and thus, by definition, $gxg^{-1}\in C_G(H)$ as wished.